# Push Topics Constant Streaming

Tags: workbench, streaming-api, pushtopic

I am trying to understand why I have a constant stream of successful handshakes within an org even though I have not explicitly subscribed to a topic. Workbench spews hundreds of successful handshakes with a handful of broken connections within minutes after selecting the Steaming Push Topcis menu item.

This behavior can be repro'd in more than one sandbox but not our production org. Any thoughts on what may be causing Workbench to produce contstant streaming activity?

[image]